# Bash script to move folders based on filesize changes?

Tags: bash, shell, move

I have some automated downloads in a proprietary linux distro.
They go to a temp scratch disk. I want to move them when they're finished to the main RAID array. The best way I can see to do this is to check the folders on the disk to see if the contents have changed in the last minute. If not then its probably finished downloading and then move it.

Assuming there could be hundreds of folders or just one in this location and its all going to the same place. Whats the best way to write this?

I can get a list of folder sizes with

```
du -h directory/name
```

The folders can contain multiple files anywhere from 1.5mb to 10GB

```
Temp Loc:  /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing
Dest Loc when complete: /volume1/S/00 Landing
```

**EDIT:**
Using this:

```
find  /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -mindepth 1 -type d -not -mmin +10 -exec mv "{}"  "/volume1/S/00 Landing" \;
find: `/volume2/4TBScratch/Processing/test': No such file or directory
4.3#
```

yet it DOES copy the relevant folders and all files. But the error worries me that something might go wrong in the future.... is it because there is multiple files and it's running the same move command for EACH file or folder in the root folder? But since it moves it all on the first iteration it cant find it on the next ones?

**EDIT2:**
Using Rsync

```
4.3# find  /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -mindepth 1 -type d -not -mmin +10 -exec rsync --remove-source-files "{}" "/volume1/S/00 Landing" \;
skipping directory newtest
skipping directory erw
```

**RESOLVED: EDIT3**
Resolved with the help in the comments below. Final script looks like this:

```
find  /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -mindepth 1 -type d -not -mmin +10 -exec rsync -a --remove-source-files "{}" "/volume1/S/00 Landing" \;
find /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

rsync to move folders and files but leaves empty root dir
the next command finds empty folders and removes them.

Thanks all!

Comment: What is the size of the folders that you want to move? and which directory do you want to move it to?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: So will it be safe to move all folders whose sizes are less then 10GB in the temp location to the actual destination location.

Comment: Yea should be. There might be rare cases where its larger but I can modify the script if i notice it becomes a regular thing. But it needs to still be able to check the size when run and then again x seconds later to ensure the size hasn't changed to make sure its not still downloading.

Comment: You don't need a script, GNU `find` command has options to find folders of certain size and move them too. Are you allowed to use `find`?

Comment: hmm..Yea find runs

Comment: Do you want to remove only the non-needed files, or whole directories? If it is just the files, you could use `rsync` for copying, with the option `--remove-source-files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GNU` [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) with options `-size` for detecting files/folders of certain size and use `mv` with the `-exec` option to move to destination directory. The syntax is

```
find /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -type d -maxdepth 1 -size -10G -exec mv "{}"  "/volume1/S/00 Landing" \;
```

Using `rsync`

```
find /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -type d -maxdepth 1 -size -10G -exec rsync --remove-source-files "{}" "/volume1/S/00 Landing" \;
```

The size with a `-` sign to indicate less than the mentioned size which in this case is `10GB`. A note on each of the flags used

- `-type d` -> For identifying only the folders from the source path.
- `-maxdepth 1` -> To look only on the current source directory and not
  being recursive.
- `-exec` -> Execute command following it.

Alternatively, if you want to find files that are last modified over a certain time(minutes), `find` has an option for `-mmin` which can be set to a value. E.g. `-mmin -5` would return files modified five minutes ago.

So suggest adding it to your requirement, for `x` as you need and see if the directories are listed, then you can add the `-exec` option for moving the directories

```
find /volume2/4TBScratch/Processing -type d -maxdepth 1 -mmin -2 -size -10G
```

Refer to the GNU documentation for [finding files according to size](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size) on how this works.

Note:- The double quotes(`""`) are added to avoid Bash from splitting the names containing spaces.

Comment: But the issue is if the file(s) in x folder are still downloading it'll be moved before it's completed. I need to make sure that the file sizes haven't changed for all files in the folder or subfolders in the last x seconds before moving the folder

Comment: I will for sure.. just getting a minor error... but its working. want to eliminate the error

Comment: @CarverStone: Cheers for that!

Comment: @CarverStone: To fix your latest error, instead of `mv` you can use `rysnc` with `--remove-source-files` as mentioned by [user1934428](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) in his comments